# Setup rubymine to execute commands over ssh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, rubymine

I'd like to setup a rails development environment where everything is running in a Ubuntu VM but I use windows 7 for display.

Under ububtu (Which is a virtualbox VM)

- ruby
- rails environment (rvm, rails, rails webserver...)
- git

Under Windows (native OS)

- browser
- IDE

I SSH into the VM for executing commands, and files are shared with nfs.

Everything works great, but I would like to try RubyMine as my editor. So in this setup I have two choices:

- Install RubyMine on windows, and configure it so it executes it's commands in the VM via SSH.
- Install RubyMine on ubuntu, and display it in windows with a X server running on windows (such as Xming) : `rubymine --display windows_ip:0`

So my question is : Is it possible to configure rubyMine so that it executes commands via SSH ?

---

I have seen [this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-10872), so my guess it that it's not currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we're working on this feature and it will be available in the next [5.0 EAP](http://eap.jetbrains.com/ruby)

Comment: is this feature in then ?